# Form Input Text Get Value from JSON Array

Tags: javascript, html, json

I made a form for my web application, some fields have value from JSON array that obtained from treatment table in the database.

```
{"treatment":[
     { "id" : 1, "name" : "Leg Training" },
     { "id" : 2, "name" : "Blood Pressure Control" },
     { "id" : 3, "name" : "MTT" },
     { "id" : 4, "name" : "Radiography" },
     { "id" : 5, "name" : "Doppler Ultrasonography" },
]}
```

Instead of select box, **I want to create input text for my form that checks the word that user wrote and recommends every similar word from key name in JSON array for user. And when user choose a word from the recommendation, it will display the word in the box but in value, it will be id-value instead the word (name-value)**, because the form will be posted in different table and as for now, it can only use id as foreign key to get the data from treatment table.

Comment: You can use the `filter()` method to return an array of all the objects where `name` contains the user input.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can understand about your question, this should get you started if you want to use purely HTML and by using **input** fields.

```html
<form method="get">

  <input name="test" type="text" list="list1" autocomplete="off"/>
    <datalist id="list1">
      <option value="1">Leg Training</option>
      <option value="2">Blood Pressure Control</option>
      <option value="3">MTT</option>
      <option value="4">Radiography</option>
      <option value="5">Doppler Ultrasonography</option>
    </datalist>
    
  <input type="submit">
  
</form>
```

The Display Text won't really be the name of disease but your users can type the name of the disease to find it from the list.

---

Let me know if you have any confusion here :)